# Show that a collection is a proper class

Tags: set-theory

I need some help with the following exercise.
Let $C$ be a proper class and $B$ a set. Show that $I=C-B$ is a proper class.

I've thought to argue by absurd. So suppose that $I$ is a set. $I$ cannot be empty because otherwise $C=B$ which is impossible. By foundation axiom we have that there exists a $y\in I$ such that $y \cap I=\varnothing$. Now I would like to find a contradiction, but I don't know if I'm following the right way. Can someone help me?

Comment: Excuse me if this is obviously wrong, but doesn't the axiom of union say that if $I$ and $B$ are both sets, then so is $I\cup B = C$?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then $\{X,Y\}$ is a set, therefore $\bigcup\{X,Y\}=X\cup Y$ is a set.

Comment: It was extremely simple! Why do I always try the most complicated way to solve exercise?? Thank you